# Is it legal to use address of one field of a union to access another field?

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
union U
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

int main()
{
    U u;
    int *p = &u.a;
    *(float *)p = 1.0f; // <-- this line
}
```

We all know that addresses of union fields are usually same, but I'm not sure is it well-defined behavior to do something like this.

So, question is: **Is it legal and well-defined behavior to cast and dereference a pointer to union field like in the code above?**

---

P.S. I know that it's more C than C++, but I'm trying to understand if it's legal in C++, not C.

Comment: Why would you? But I'm pretty sure it would be legal, since *all* union members start at the same address. (Otherwise, it wouldn't be a union anymore.)

Comment: it is legal but not recommended

Comment: As others have said, legal or otherwise, it is bad design! Semantically, A union should contain exactly one of its members.  What you're trying to do sounds "clever", and you have to be twice as clever to fix a bug as you were when you created it.  Don't be clever if there is another way.

Comment: How is it more C than C++?  Unions exist in both languages and so do pointers.

Comment: @owacoder @Daniel Ohh, it's a long story. I'm trying to implement GLSL-style vectors. For them, I need a behavior like this: `vec3 a(1,2,3); vec4 b = a.zxyy; // 3,1,2,2` To implement that behavior (`.zxyy`) i need the vector class to be a union. One of it's fields is a structure with  x, y, z and w members. Other fields are letter combinations like `zxyy`. For each such field I need a separate (empty) type and a separate set of (macro-generated) overloaded operators.

Comment: These overloaded operators shall somehow access x, y, z and w fields. The only way I see is to cast an address of such empty class to pointer to an entire vector and then use `->x`, `->y`, `->z`, `->w` on it.

Comment: @vishal Yes, I think it is, but I can't be sure without a reference from the standard...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I mean, it's more C-style than C++-style.

Comment: Let's amend, *first* field, to access other *first* field. If there's type mismatch and e.g. this is a union of structs, third field of the first struct may be entirely elsewhere than the third field of the second struct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All members of a union must reside at the same address, that is guaranteed by the standard. What you are doing is indeed *well-defined* behavior, but it shall be noted that you cannot read from an *inactive* member of a union using the same approach.

- [Accessing inactive union member - undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/1090079)

> <sub>**Note**: Do not use c-style casts, prefer `reinterpret_cast` in this case.</sub>

---

As long as all you do is **write** to the other data-member of the `union`, the behavior is well-defined; but as stated this changes which is considered to be the *active* member of the `union`; meaning that you can later only read from that you just wrote to.

```
union U {
    int a;
    float b;
};

int main () {
    U u;
    int *p = &u.a;
    reinterpret_cast<float*> (p) = 1.0f; // ok, well-defined
}
```

> <sub>**Note**: There is an exception to the above rule when it comes to *layout-compatible* types.</sub>

---

The question can be rephrased into the following snippet which is semantically equivalent to a boiled down version of the "problem".

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main () {
  using union_storage_t = std::aligned_storage<
    std::max ( sizeof(int),   sizeof(float)),
    std::max (alignof(int),  alignof(float))
  >::type;

  union_storage_t u;

  int   * p1 = reinterpret_cast<  int*> (&u);
  float * p2 = reinterpret_cast<float*> (p1);
  float * p3 = reinterpret_cast<float*> (&u);

  assert (p2 == p3); // will never fire
}
```

---

#### What does the Standard ([`n3797`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) say?

> ```
> 9.5/1    Unions    [class.union]
> ```
>
> > In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be
> >     active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the 
> >     non-static dat amembers ca nbe stored in a union at any time.
> >     [...] The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of
> >     its non-static data members. Each non-static data member is
> >     allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct. All non-static data members of a union object have the same address.

> <sub>**Note**: The wording in C++11 ([**n3337**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) was underspecified, even though the intent has always been that of C++14.</sub>

Comment: I guess it's underspecified, see [CWG 1116](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1116)

Comment: @KerrekSB I will change to make the post reference C++14, since the wording is more clear (but the intent has always been that wording - even in C++11).

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how writing to the `reinterpret_cast`'ed pointer doesn't violate the strict alias rules, regardless of what you can do with the union afterwards?

Comment: @MarkB since the data-members are to be placed at the same address, the `reinterpret_cast` is fine (since we can interpret this address as the start of an object of type `T2` - even though it currently holds an object of type `T1`).

Comment: @MarkB see the added example.

Comment: "Note: There is an exception to the above rule when it comes to layout-compatible types." Where?

Comment: If you meant the "standard-layout `struct`s with common initial sequence" proviso, some people claim it only guarantees behaviour when the `union` is passed to the user (making its declaration visible) and punning is done by reading the `struct` initial members via `union` member accessors ('punning' `u.structA.a` and `u.structB.b`, not just `structA` and `structB`). I'm not convinced, but the wording is badly ambiguous. If there is a section that sets defined behaviour for reads/writes from/to different layout-compatible `union` members, treated as individual objects, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is legal.  Using explicit casts, you can do almost anything.

As other comments have stated, all members in a `union` start at the same address / location so casting a pointer to a different member is pointless.

The assembly language will be the same.  You want to make the code easy to read so I don't recommend the practice.  It is confusing and there is no benefit.

Also, I recommend a "type" field so that you know when the data is in `float` format versus `int` format.