# Does the C++17 standard guarantee that the address of a union is the same as the address of its members?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, unions, allocator

I am currently working on programming a pool allocator. My question boils down to the following code:

```
template <typename T>
union myUnion {
    T data;
    myUnion<T>* nextUnion;
};

void someFunction(){
    myUnion<T> mu;
    T* t = new (std::addressof(mu.data)) T();
    //some code
    myUnion<T>* mu2 = reinterpret_cast<myUnion<T>*>(t);
}
```

Is the address of mu always the same as mu2?

Comment: Which standard?

Comment: What would be the point of the union otherwise?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Almost everything else about it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The standard specifies that " unions ... are classes capable of containing objects of different types at different times". That's their point.

Comment: Whatever the standard says, `T* t = new (std::addressof(mu.data)) T();` is probably not a good idea if there is any non-trivial constructor or destructor involved.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Why? T inside the Union is unconstructed during the union creation and thus any constructor call should work. Calling the destructor properly afterwards when the element is given back to the allocator should also be valid. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher sorry my bad, if there are constructors or destructors of T involved you just need to provide the same for myUnion .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes.**

9.2/19 (12.2/24 in N4659):

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member.

If the union itself is standard-layout, then the address of the union is the same as its members'.

The addresses of the members are all the same, thanks to 9.5/1 (12.3/2 in N4659):

> Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a
>   struct. All non-static data members of a union object have the same address.

Comment: Isn't this §9.2/20 in C++11/C++14?

Comment: @Cameron: There is no 9.2/20 in C++14.

Comment: It's 9.2/19 in the draft I have. Don't have the actual standard, it's too expensive.

Comment: @Fanael: Please refer to standards, not drafts. (Having said that, I agree with this answer)

Comment: Weird, it's 9.2/20 in the one I have (N4296).

Comment: @Cameron: Then that is not C++14.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I will, if you give me 200 CHF. That said, it'd be useless: the content of N4140 is identical to the actual standard.

Comment: @Cameron: but there's no 9.2/19 in my copy of N4140.

Comment: Ah, just realized I was reading the "revises" field. I actually have N4296.

Comment: Probably more relevant is "9.5/1 Unions   ... Each non-static data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct.  All non-static data members of a union object have the same address."  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33056605/4756299  Just find the reference that says what the address of the first element of a `struct` is.

Comment: Both passages are pertinent, surely.

Comment: @Cameron Both answers are pertinent, but if `T` isn’t standard-layout, then the union won’t be either.

Comment: @Fanael N4140 isn't actually the same as the standard; it's got a lot more editorial fixes. N4141 is the C++14 IS.

Comment: @T.C. Fair point, but I wouldn't exactly say "a lot more". The differences are pretty minor, and none apply to the quoted passages.

Comment: @Fanael The current version of your answer doesn’t say that it works for non–standard layout `T` (which allocators often need to deal with). I think `struct` layout guarantees that it works, though.

Comment: The clauses about pointer-interconvertible would improve this answer.  Ie, what does "same address" mean as far as the standard is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to ask if two objects have the same address. For instance, an array and its first element are guaranteed to have the same address, [but you cannot cast one to the other](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#note-4).

Fortunately, union and its members are guaranteed to be [pointer-interconvertible](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-note-2), regardless of whether any of them is standard layout.